# How to aggregate POSIXlt by day to find daily peaks?

Tags: r, date, select, aggregate, threshold

I have a variant of this question: [Count values in a data set that exceed a threshold in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872125/count-values-in-a-data-set-that-exceed-a-threshold-in-r):

I have some temperature measurement at almost random time intervals. I want to find out on which (how many) days a specific threshold value had been exceeded (in some time frame). Obviously without aggregating I could get multiple hits for the same day (if the threshold was exceeded multiple times). However I don't want that.

A short sample of the original data frame looks like this:

```
                 Time Temp Humidity Notes
1 2015-05-18 16:00:00 26.5       NA  <NA>
2 2015-06-01 15:00:00 26.5       NA  <NA>
3 2015-06-02 16:00:00 28.0       NA  <NA>
4 2015-06-03 16:00:00 28.0       NA  <NA>
5 2015-06-03 17:00:00 30.0       60  <NA>
6 2015-06-05 07:00:00 23.0       NA  <NA>
```

So I computed a `Day` variable (`POSIXlt`):

```
1 2015-05-18 16:00:00 26.5       NA  <NA> 2015-05-18
2 2015-06-01 15:00:00 26.5       NA  <NA> 2015-06-01
3 2015-06-02 16:00:00 28.0       NA  <NA> 2015-06-02
4 2015-06-03 16:00:00 28.0       NA  <NA> 2015-06-03
5 2015-06-03 17:00:00 30.0       60  <NA> 2015-06-03
6 2015-06-05 07:00:00 23.0       NA  <NA> 2015-06-05
```

I almost despaired trying to aggregate by day (I'm not showing all the variants I had tried):

```
with(t, aggregate(Temp ~ Day, data=t, FUN=max))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Temp ~ Day, data = t) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'Day'
```

Only if I explicitly convert `POSIXlt` to `POSIXct`, it works (why have a class `POSTXlt` that is treated as a list by aggregate?):

```
> with(t, aggregate(Temp ~ as.POSIXct(Day), data=t, FUN=max))
  as.POSIXct(Day) Temp
1      2015-05-18 26.5
2      2015-06-01 26.5
3      2015-06-02 28.0
4      2015-06-03 30.0
5      2015-06-05 23.0
```

Unfortunately I've lost the other columns during aggregate. How can I preserve them?

Also I don't understand this:

```
> tt <-with(t, aggregate(Temp ~ as.POSIXct(Day), data=t, FUN=max))
> tt
  as.POSIXct(Day) Temp
1      2015-05-18 26.5
2      2015-06-01 26.5
3      2015-06-02 28.0
4      2015-06-03 30.0
5      2015-06-05 23.0
> str(tt)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ as.POSIXct(Day): POSIXct, format: "2015-05-18" "2015-06-01" ...
 $ Temp           : num  26.5 26.5 28 30 23
> tt$Temp > 25
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> tt[tt$Temp > 25]
Error in `[.data.frame`(tt, tt$Temp > 25) : undefined columns selected
> tt[tt$Temp > 25,]
  as.POSIXct(Day) Temp
1      2015-05-18 26.5
2      2015-06-01 26.5
3      2015-06-02 28.0
4      2015-06-03 30.0
> t$Temp > 25
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> t[t$Temp > 25]
                 Time Temp Humidity Notes        Day
1 2015-05-18 16:00:00 26.5       NA  <NA> 2015-05-18
2 2015-06-01 15:00:00 26.5       NA  <NA> 2015-06-01
3 2015-06-02 16:00:00 28.0       NA  <NA> 2015-06-02
4 2015-06-03 16:00:00 28.0       NA  <NA> 2015-06-03
5 2015-06-03 17:00:00 30.0       60  <NA> 2015-06-03
6 2015-06-05 07:00:00 23.0       NA  <NA> 2015-06-05
```

Why did `aggregate()` change the structure of `t`? Can someone explain what I'm missing?

For reference, there's the sample data set (that has another variable `Tim` (`difftime`) holding the measurement offset from the start of day) in `dput()` format:

```
> dput(t)
structure(list(Time = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(16L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 7L), mday = c(18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L), mon = c(4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), 
    wday = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L), yday = c(137L, 151L, 152L, 
    153L, 153L, 155L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    )), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", 
"wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), Temp = c(26.5, 26.5, 28, 28, 30, 23), Humidity = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 60, NA), Notes = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    Day = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(18L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L), mon = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), year = c(115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L), yday = c(137L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 153L, 155L), isdst = c(-1L, 
    -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), zone = c("CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
    "CEST", "CEST", "CEST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
    "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
    "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), Tim = structure(c(16, 
    15, 16, 16, 17, 7), class = "difftime", units = "hours")), .Names = c("Time", 
"Temp", "Humidity", "Notes", "Day", "Tim"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `dplyr`? Something like `t %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise(max = max(Temp)`

Comment: @Richard Telford: Obviously no, but can you add the result of your suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three solutions using `dplyr`, `data.table` and a `split`-`lapply` combination without any package:

In every case convert `Time` to `POSIXct` and `Day` to `Date` (I called the dataset you gave sample here and choose 27 as a cutoff, so we have one Day with two matching rows.):

```
sample$Time <- as.POSIXct(sample$Time)
sample$Day  <- as.Date(sample$Day)
```

With `dplyr`, the verbs speak for themselves, this is why this is my favourite solution:

```
require(dplyr)

result <- sample %>% 
          group_by(Day) %>% 
          summarise(greater27=max(Temp > 27))

result
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#          Day greater27
#       <date>     <int>
# 1 2015-05-18         0
# 2 2015-06-01         0
# 3 2015-06-02         1
# 4 2015-06-03         1
# 5 2015-06-05         0
```

With `data.table`, leave the first argument empty to select all lines, do the calculation in the second argument, and specify `by` as named argument:

```
require(data.table)

sample <- data.table(sample)
result <- sample[, .(greater27=max(Temp > 27)), by="Day"]

result
#           Day greater27
# 1: 2015-05-18         0
# 2: 2015-06-01         0
# 3: 2015-06-02         1
# 4: 2015-06-03         1
# 5: 2015-06-05         0
```

And with just base R, `split` the dataset by `Day` this gives you a list of `data.frames` then apply the anonymous function, finally `rbind` everything back together to one data.frame:

```
result <- do.call(rbind, 
                  lapply(split(sample, sample$Day),
                         function(x){
                           data.frame(
                             Day = x$Day[1],
                             greater27 = max(x$Temp > 27)
                           )
                         }
                    )
            )

result
#                   Day greater27
# 2015-05-18 2015-05-18         0
# 2015-06-01 2015-06-01         0
# 2015-06-02 2015-06-02         1
# 2015-06-03 2015-06-03         1
# 2015-06-05 2015-06-05         0
```

Comment: Could you please give at least one line and the number of rows of the corresponding results?

Comment: Edited to include output.

Comment: I also changed the `data.table` example, so that the column of the output is named correctly.

Comment: Thanks! So you produce a table with the time and an Boolean-type "selected" column, while my approach tried a row-select of the original data (in case I want to do more with those).

Comment: In the `dplyr` version you can just add a `filter` to the chain to select only the right rows. In the other solutions the best way to select the rows is probably to do it in two steps, create the boolean and then select by it.